# best practice for loading large image gallery

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, load

I have an unexpectedly large gallery of 130 images. Originally, my approach was to fade in the gallery on `$(window).load();`

Clearly this is laughable at 130 files.. And really, nobody wants to deal with that many http requests anyway.

So that's my "subjective question that's likely to be closed."

I'm reluctantly thinking that maybe I should load only 20 or so images and then ajax-in more as the user progresses in the gallery. But that is uncharted and scary sounding.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially load a few images then use preloader for other images..

Common jquery gallery does this look for gallerific :
<del>http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/</del>
**Updated**: https://github.com/iamvery/galleriffic

If you want to build solution manually you can use preloader :
http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript

Comment: going to try and rope galleriffic into my existing functions. the navigation isn't based on thumbnails or scrolling.. just one image at a time. thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea to only load the I ages as the user requires them, by either only showing 10-20 at a time with a "view more" or "next page" link somewhere on your page. Another way of doing it would be to load images as the user scrolls down your page! Using the scroll() method, documented here: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

I would go with the separate pages whereby you use jQuery to load the next set of images when the user clicks the different links.

Answer (score 0):

Definetly the best way is as you writed, to load only some of the images and then to load the rest.

My suggestion is to load only 3-5 images and to add event for "next" button to load more. Find the jquery.lazyload.js and try to integrate to your page.

Comment: According to it's page lazyload is broken in newer browsers. (The jQuery plugin that is...)

Comment: Am using it and everything works fine... I  tested in IE8/IE9 and FF 6 and everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

This is a subjective question, however, the basic answer is to load images *after* the page has loaded, so you don't block the page.

You should also be using thumbnails. I have seen plenty of home-made galleries that just squashes the original picture down to a thumbnail on load... That's not nice ;) If you don't want to go the next/prev-page route, you could just load thumbnails in a 5/6/7-by-infinite grid, and only load pictures in visible placeholders.

1. Load page
2. Create placeholders for every picture
3. Load pictures for visible placeholders
4. as the user scrolls down the page, load pictures for the placeholders that come in to the viewport.

Or something ;)